# Implication of Matrices in $AX=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logic

I'm not sure how to phrase my question and this is the first time I'm posting on math exchange but basically I'm looking for some feedback on my answer to this question:

Let $A$ denote an $m×n$ matrix. If $AX=0$ for every $n×1$ matrix $X$, show that $A=0$.

I claim that since $X$ is every column vector in the set $R^n$, and $AX=0$, it is implied that $A=0$ by considering the constituents of the products of $AX$: $a_j×x_i$ where $a_j$ represents the $j$th column of $A$ and $x_i$ represents the $i$th row of $X$, and $i=j$.

If $a_j×x_i=0$ and vector $X$ is every possible column vector (where $x_i=n$), then it's implied that $A$ must be a zero matrix (where $a_j=0$) to satisfy the equation $AX=0$.

I feel like I'm running in circles with this argument...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  In particular, $X$ can be taken to be the same as any row of $A$; then the dot product of that row with itself must be $0$, so that row must be the $0$ vector; and that works for any row

Comment: Do you know about nullspaces?

Comment: If X is not the zero vector (and from your question,  it clearly isn't), then what does that mean in terms of the trivial solution of this homogeneous equation?

Comment: @imranfat the trivial solution must have zeroes as coefficients since $X$ isn't the zero vector, so $A=0$... well that's a pretty concise solution

Comment: @broncoAbierto Not really, they haven't come up in the textbook yet :(

Comment: Since nobody else did, I feel like it's important to explicitly point out your intuition is true: you are running circles with your argument. You're not proving the statement, you're just rephrasing it. If you know something is true for every $X$, and you need to use that information to prove something, very often (but not always) it is sufficient to fill in a very specific $X$ and see what results you get. This is exactly what the answers are all doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that any matrix $A$ multiplied by the $i$th standard basis vector $e_i$ (whose $i$th coordinate is $1$ and the rest is $0$) gives the $i$th column of $A$.

Apply this for $X=e_1,\dots, e_n$ to show that every column of $A$ is the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

With

$A = [a_{ij}] \tag 1$

and

$X = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)^T, \tag 2$

it is easy to see that

$AX = \left (\displaystyle \sum_1^n a_{1k}x_k , \sum_1^n a_{2k} x_k, \ldots, \sum_1^n a_{mk} x_k \right )^T; \tag 3$

since $X$ is arbitrary, we are free to choose

$x_k = \delta_{kj} \tag 4$

for any $j$; then (3) becomes

$AX = (a_{1j}, a_{2j}, \ldots, a_{mj}); \tag 5$

but we are given that this vanishes for any choice of $X$; thus

$a_{ij} = 0, \; 1 \le i \le m; \tag 6$

allowing $j$ to run from $1$ to $n$ shows that

$a_{ij} = 0, \; 1 \le i \le m, \; 1 \le j \le n, \tag 7$

whence

$A = 0. \tag 8$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ is not the $m\times n$ zero matrix. That is, for some index $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, 
the $j$-th column $A_j$ of $A$ is not the $m\times 1$ zero matrix. Let $X$ be the $n\times 1$ matrix whose only nonzero entry is a $1$ on its $j$-th row. $AX=A_j$ is nonzero.